# JQuery Masonry ! Update columnWidth On Window Resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, window-resize

I'm working working on Responsive Layout where I'm using JQuery Masonry as well.

I'm using following script to get current column width.

```
var curWidth; 
var detector;

detector = $('.magic-column');
curWidth = detector.outerWidth(true);

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(detector.outerWidth(true)!=curWidth){
        curWidth = detector.outerWidth(true);
    }
});
```

My JQuery Masonry init script is something like this..

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $(function (){
            $wall.masonry({
                    singleMode: true, 
                    columnWidth: curWidth, // This needs to be update on window load & resize both //
            });
     });
});
```

My 1st script is fetching width correctly, but in masonry that width isn't updating... 
How can I implement both load & resize function so that my curWidth will be updated for Masonry as well on window resize

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the columnWidth of the masonry after resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(detector.outerWidth(true)!=curWidth){
        curWidth = detector.outerWidth(true);
        $wall.masonry( 'option', { columnWidth: curWidth });
    }
});
```

Yuo can read more about the masonry methods here: http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html

Comment: Hi, the link you are sharing in your answer is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 1):

bindResize can be used to resize all items in the container when using a fluid layout (`bindResize` is in `https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/dist/masonry.pkgd.js`

```
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.container'
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $container.masonry('bindResize')
});
```